# Jekyll cannot load such file -- jekyll-watch

Tags: jekyll

All of the sudden I get this error when I run jekyll serve.

cannot load such file -- jekyll-watch

Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have jekyll-watch or one of its dependencies installed.
In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. The full error message fro
m Ruby is: 'cannot load such file -- jekyll-watch' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources
at http://jekyllrb.com/help/!

I've got no clue how to fix this. Does someone else have this problem?

gem list jekyll-watch  show me

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

jekyll-watch (1.2.1)

Comment: try a bundle update? Or if you have a `Gemfile.lock` in your repo, go back a few revisions? I've had weird errors at times when a certain gem somehow causes older gems to be defaulted to instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have this problem and solved below command line

```
gem install GEM_NAME_HERE
```

if you run in after OSX el Capitan use blow command line

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin GEM_NAME_HERE
```